# Removing data from a datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
 int rowCount = dataGridViewLay.RowCount-1;
       // int columnCount = dataGridViewLay.ColumnCount;

        MessageBox.Show(rowCount+" ");


            for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {

                String layDate = dataGridViewLay.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    if (!layDate.Equals(layDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString()))
                    {

                       // MessageBox.Show("Match Found");

                         dataGridViewLay.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
            }
```

I used the above code, but there popped up an exception; a NullReferenceException and I cannot understand the reason for that anybody have an idea about this?

Comment: On which line does the exception happen?

Comment: at the "String layDate= dataGridViewLay.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();" line

Comment: So make sure that your rows have cells before accessing it

Comment: I would have look at the line `dataGridViewLay.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value`. Are you sure that the the cell `Cells[1]` is populated?

Comment: If the problem is line with value then debug. Check what is actually null there.
dataGridViewLay.Rows[i]?
dataGridViewLay.Rows[i].Cells[1]?
dataGridViewLay.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value?
check why. If this is a correct situation add a check for null value.

Answer (score 0):

You should not *cache* the length:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridViewLay.RowCount-1; i++)
{
...
}
```

Regarding `NullReferenceException`: `layDate` may become null if in any `Row` you have `Cell[1]` null. And then `null.ToString()` is an exception.

This will work

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridViewLay.RowCount-1; i++)
    if(somecondition)
        dataGridViewLay.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

and it's equal to

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewLay.RowCount; i++)
    if(somecondition)
        dataGridViewLay.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

in a way what you get same result. It's not optimal, but it *works* and *is not a mistake*.

Comment: -1 This is still a problem

Comment: Why would you subtract 1? Why not just use < instead of <= and avoid having to subtract 1?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, It will solve the most *obvious* problem with that design. Why `NullReferenceException` occurs - nobody knows yet.

Comment: @Highace2, it doesn't matter, i just take OP code.

Comment: I have already done that for precautions. But it is not the real problem, the problem is that the String layDate is being passed by a null reference, and I want to know how to avoid that. I already used exceptions adn it works but leaves one value left behind which matches the criteria.

Comment: @Sinatr 1) This will still give terrible result, `dataGridViewLay.Rows.RemoveAt(i);` re arranges the rows, 2)`i <= dataGridViewLay.RowCount-1` is second problem, 3) doesn't answers the question

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, you are fast at posting, care to read my edit/comments?

Comment: @Sinatr I removed my downvote, you addressed my point 3, but not 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

After you delete the first row the number of rows decrease while your count is still the same. You should iterate from the end.

```
for (int i = dataGridViewLay.RowCount-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: For Loop with 4 Defination?? For(Initialization;ConditionChecking;???;Decrement)  why so

Answer (score 0):

You Referencing Row of DatagridView through `i` and your `i` refering a row which is not in DataGridView

On

```
dataGridViewLay.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

It Points to a row which is not present in grid or it did'nt Get a referance of row which have to remove from Datagridview thus you got Null Reference exception
**So try to find out at which row you getting this exeption**

For more Detail [Null Refernce Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

### Try this

```
foreach( DataGridViewRow dgr in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r != null).ToList())
 { 
   //remove Those rows Which is not equal to null             
 }
```

Comment: try this @user3167860

Answer (score 0):

It's is just a suggestion but when you find the layDate thingy then you could break out of the loop (the `break`keyword). This would avoid the number of rows not being the same as your cached row count.